# Roots of a real exponential sum

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, numerical-optimization, exponential-sum

Suppose I had some exponential sum $\ f(x)\ $ of the form:
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left( c_i \ e^{a_i x} \right)$$
where:
$$c_i, a_i \in R$$
$$a_i \leq 0$$
Is there a quick way to find the roots, $\ \ f(x) = 0\ $?

Comment: Consider the special case where $a_i = i-1$, so that $f(\log x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} c_i x^{i-1}$ with $x>0$. This tells that the problem is at least as hard as determining positive zeros of *arbitrary polynomial*, which is already extremely hard and almost impossible to come up with a master answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this actually isn't a special case, because $a_i \leq 0$, right? But I suppose you could just define $a_i := 1 - i$. Hmm...

Comment: As you pointed out, we may still consider the case $a_i = 1-i$ and my point of opposition remains the same.

Comment: If we had some known $\lambda_i$ for each $i$, would it help to know that $\sum_{i = 1}^N c_i / \lambda_i = 1$?

Comment: and $\lambda_i \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: There is some theory on functions of this structure in Khovanskii: Fewnominals, (if you can find it in your library) which extends on ideas around the BKK theorem, (Bernstein–Khovanskii–Kushnirenko).